# MongoDB: Retrieve most referenced document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection (called 'links') with documents like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8abd4c66b0e3cf12665"),
    "name" : "Pet 4056 AgR",
    "file" : "P0001J01",
    "quotes" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8afd4c66b0e3cf15173"),
            "name" : "Pet 4837 ED",
            "file" : "P1103J03"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8b6d4c66b0e3cf19425"),
            "name" : "ACO 845 AgR",
            "file" : "P2810J07"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8afd4c66b0e3cf14a77"),
            "name" : "ACO 1574 AgR",
            "file" : "P0924J05"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my db, this means that this document references 3 other documents. 
For each document, in its `quotes` array there are no two documents with the same id/name/file. The `name` field is unique in the collection.

Now, I need to get the document that is the most referenced. It's the document that appears in most `quotes` arrays. How can I do that?
I believe this is achieved through an aggregation, but I can't figure out how to do it, especially because the names are inside an array.

Thanks! :)

Comment: How about you add an additional field into each document to hold the reference count? So you could update and maintain the reference count whenever other document quote it, and later query and sort it easily.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, could be done! However I think it's safer to unwind and group as you suggested in the answer, in case someone in the future wants to add more documents and forgets to update the reference counts. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the aggregation framework, but a key feature to working with arrays is that you use the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline operation to first "de-normalize" the array content as separate documents:

```js
db.links.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$quotes" },

    // Group by the inner "name" value and count the occurrences
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$quotes.name",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Sort to the highest count on top
    { "$sort": { "count": 1 } },

    // Just return the largest value
    { "$limit": 1 }

])
```

So what `$unwind` does here is for each array element it takes a copy of the "outer" document that owns the array and produces a new document containing the outer and just the singular array element. Basically like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8abd4c66b0e3cf12665"),
    "name" : "Pet 4056 AgR",
    "file" : "P0001J01",
    "quotes" : 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8afd4c66b0e3cf15173"),
            "name" : "Pet 4837 ED",
            "file" : "P1103J03"
        }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8abd4c66b0e3cf12665"),
    "name" : "Pet 4056 AgR",
    "file" : "P0001J01",
    "quotes" : 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("544bc8b6d4c66b0e3cf19425"),
            "name" : "ACO 845 AgR",
            "file" : "P2810J07"
        }
}
```

This allows other aggregation pipeline stages to access content just as any normal document, so you can [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the occurrences on "quotes.name" without a problem.

Take a good look at all of the [aggregation pipeline operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), it is worth understanding what they all do.

Comment: Very nice solution, unwinding makes it much clearer. I believe the `"count": 1` bit should be `"count": -1` for descending order, right?